# RAID1 as a personal desktop backup system, pros and cons

Tags: linux, filesystems, backup, raid1

I'm seriously considering ways to safeguard my data since I'm really tired of loosing files because of bad redundancy.

I was reading about RAID1 and it seems a very practical method of keeping updated backups, though I'm worried about complexity, security, flexibility and portability.

By complexity I mean that I'm adding another logical layer to the filesystem, so in case that anything goes wrong, maintaining and securing both layers may result in added complexity.

How do you rescue data from a RAID1 system? Is it more complex than a normal ext4?

By security I mean that redundancy is double sharped because an error in the upper ext4 filesystem would affect both drives simultaneously because both drives are readed and written at the same time. Is there any means to prevent this?

By flexibility I mean, what happens if one of the mirrored drives breaks up and I'm not able to afford another drive? can I maintain a RAID1 system with only one drive indefinitely? also is it possible to simplify a raid1 system back to a normal ext4 partition?

1. How do you rescue data from a RAID1 system? Is it more complex than a normal ext4?
2. Is there any way to delay mirroring in a RAID1 system?
3. can I maintain a RAID1 system with only one drive indefinitely? also is it possible to simplify a raid1 system back to a normal ext4 partition?
4. By portability I mean how to move a RAID filesystem in between computers?

Edit: I could mantain Raid1 in degraded mode by keeping the mirror drive as inactive and periodically reintegrate it so that filesystem integrity could be safe.

Comment: [*Why is RAID not a backup?*](https://serverfault.com/a/3697)

Comment: you should also consider using zfs instead of just mdadm raid-1.  In a mirror configuration, it gives the same benefits as raid-1 plus snapshot and transparent compression and many other features.   Unlike raid-1, you can't mount and use the raw partitions without zfs (but you can still run in degraded mode for as long as you like).   Alternatively, btrfs offers similar features to zfs.

Answer (score 2):

RAID covers against a drive going bad, and in particular, a drive going bad in a way that very clearly says "I'm broken", either by returning errors to some read request, or just not answering at all.

It **doesn't** protect against the drive silently corrupting data (they have error correction, of course, but it's still not unheard of), the filesystem getting corrupted, a power surge blowing up all the drives, a fire destroying the machine, or the user just plain old deleting the wrong file.

If that one drive fails, the RAID driver/controller should bring up the array in a "degraded" state, where it works as usual (except maybe slowed), but doesn't have any redundancy. Depending on the system, it's also possible that the halves of a mirror are also readable as regular drives. This works if all the RAID related metadata is at the end of the device. With Linux mdadm RAID, that's the case with superblock version 1.0, but you have to explicitly specify that when creating the array.

---

What you *should* do, is to make proper backups to another computer, preferably off-site, such that earlier versions of the data is also kept. Even if you don't do that, a cheap-ass solution of making an additional mirrored partition and filesystem on top of the same drives and storing backups there is still better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

> an error in the upper ext4 filesystem would affect both drives simultaneously because both drives are readed and written at the same time. Is there any means to prevent this?

None that I'm aware of.

> By flexibility I mean, what happens if one of the mirrored drives breaks up and I'm not able to afford another drive? can I maintain a RAID1 system with only one drive indefinitely?

You can run RAID1 in degraded mode (i.e. with a single drive) for as long as you want.

> also is it possible to simplify a raid1 system back to a normal ext4 partition?

No. You'll have to delete your RAID partition and create a simple ext4 partition, and as far as I'm aware you cannot do that in place.

> How do you rescue data from a RAID1 system? Is it more complex than a normal ext4?

Just like you do with a normal system. No.

> Is there any way to delay mirroring in a RAID1 system?

`echo "idle" >  /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action`

> can I maintain a RAID1 system with only one drive indefinitely? also is it possible to simplify a raid1 system back to a normal ext4 partition?

Yes. No, not directly.

> By portability I mean how to move a RAID filesystem in between computers?

Linux software RAID can be freely moved between PCs.

P.S. I recommend that you strongly consider **offsite backups** (perhaps encrypted ones). That's the most secure way to provide real redundancy to your data which RAID does **not** actually provide. RAID helps only against a hardware failure, not against a software failure or human errors (i.e. you accidentally deleting files or formatting data).

Comment: For mdadm raid-1 (but not other raid levels) you **can** just mount and use the raw partitions without raid.  e.g. if /dev/md0 is a raid-1 mirror of /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1 that is formatted with ext4, you can mount /dev/md0 (and have raid-1 active) OR you can mount /dev/sda1 OR /dev/sdb1 (and have just plain ext4).   It's one of the benefits of mdadm software raid over hardware raid and fakeraid.    This is mostly useful in recovery/emergency situations, because it's a PITA to manually keep track of which raw partition is up-to-date.